# Default value from DTD in xStream

Tags: dtd, xstream

Geven XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ExternalRequestContext [
<!ELEMENT ExternalRequestContext EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST ExternalRequestContext
 requestType CDATA #REQUIRED
 deepEnrichment (true | false) "false"
 channelMandatory (true | false) "true">
]
>

<ExternalRequestContext requestType="News" deepEnrichment="false" />
```

And xStream code

```
@XStreamAlias("ExternalRequestContext")
class ERC {
 private String requestType;
 private boolean deepEnrichment;
 private boolean channelMandatory;
}
...
XStream x = new XStream();
x.processAnnotations(ERC.class);
ERC erc = (ERC)x.fromXML(new FileReader("C:/Projects/Forwarder/Test.xml"));
x.toXML(erc, System.out);
```

My browser renders it as following:

```
<ExternalRequestContext requestType="News" deepEnrichment="false" channelMandatory="true" />
```

Note that **channelMandatory="true"** (browser processed the DTD instruction)

while xStream produces

```
<ExternalRequestContext>
  <deepEnrichment>false</deepEnrichment>
  <channelMandatory>false</channelMandatory>
</ExternalRequestContext>
```

Here **channelMandatory="false"** (xStream ignored the "channelMandatory (true | false) "true"" DTD instruction)

What do I miss? How to "tell" xStream to process DTD instructions?
And how do I enable DTD validation in xStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because you're using the primitive `boolean` type. When class `ERC` is instantiated, the `channelMandatory` field is initialized by java to `false`. Since the document contains no data for that field, it stays at `false`.

DTD validation in java is just that - validation. It doesn't modify the document, it leaves it as it was, it just permits `channelMandatory` to be not present, knowing that it has a default value. If a web browser chooses to do other wise, that's fine, but that's going beyond validation.

You could try the simplest potential solution - initialise the `channelMandatory` field to `true`, e.g.

```
@XStreamAlias("ExternalRequestContext")
class ERC {
 private String requestType;
 private boolean deepEnrichment = false;
 private boolean channelMandatory = true;
}
```

That would probably work fine. This is the approach that JAXB takes for generating a java object model from a schema, I think.

Comment: Fine! Using a wrapper class instead of primitive type can indicate whether a value was given in the XML file.
Explicit initialization, however, didn't work: I get channelMandatory is false regardless its initial value.
Regarding to validation: can I make xStream to throw an exception if I feed it with invalid (but well-formed) XML?